# How do i override equal in ruby with nil fields?

Tags: ruby

I am not sure how to make the following test cases pass. I use source for union (|) and inside list.include?(source)

```
 class Source
  # mongoid object code...
  def hash
    url.hash
  end

  def ==(other)
    eql?(other)
  end

  def eql?(other_source)
    url = self.url and other_source and url == other_source.url
  end
end
```

TestCase:

```
  ext1 = Source.new
  ext2 = Source.new(url: "test")

  (ext2.== ext1).should               == false # false
  (ext1.== ext2).should               == false # is returning nil instead of false
```

I would like to have the last case return false instead of nil but am not sure how to ge this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common pattern for this is to "double bang" the expression:

```
!!(url = self.url && other_source && url == other_source.url)
```

This will coerce any value to `true` or `false`.

(Also, [the Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) recommends using `&&` and `||` in place of `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code and hit the line

```
  ext2 = Source.new(url: "test")
```

I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)`, so I'm not sure if this will work, but maybe you meant

```
  def eql?(other_source)
    url == self.url and other_source and url == other_source.url
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why the url variable at all?

```
# if they need to be the same class to be equal
def eql(other_source)
  Source === other_source && other_source.url == self.url
end

# OR, if it just matters that it responds to url
def eql(other_source)
  other_source.respond_to?(:url) && other_source.url == self.url
end
```

Note that just testing for the truthiness of `other_source` won't prevent an exception if it's truthy and still doesn't have a url property, so your current solution would raise an exception if you said, for example `ext1 == true`

This is not to mention that in your example, `ext1` could never be `eql` to *anything*, as the first thing you're testing is the existence of `self.url`.  Is this what you want?  Wouldn't at least two sources with no `url` be considered equal if that is the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you forgot to paste some of your code, but I think you meant something like this:

```
class Source
  attr_reader :url

  def initialize(params = {})
    @url = params[:url]
  end

  def hash
    @url.hash
  end

  def ==(other)
    eql?(other)
  end

  def eql?(other_source)
    other_source && @url == other_source.url
  end
end
```

That solves your problem while fixing several others:

1. You need an instance variable named `url` and a getter for it.
2. You need an `initialize` method.

`eql?` then only needs to make sure `other_source` is not `nil` and compare `url`s:

```
ext2.== ext1 # => false
ext1.== ext2 # => false
```